# How to add extra js script into Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am creating a website (Laravel + Vue.js) where in admin panel, I have to attach a script which will style checbox but Vue is not letting me add

```
<script></script>
```

tag more than one and also does not show any error.
I have tried to place the script in multiple places but nothing happened.
I have tried to show them without vuejs and they look like this:
[image]
But in Vue.js they dont appear.

[image]
Can Anybody tell me the solution for it ?

**Code:**

```
<template>
...
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
     <div class="col-lg-4" >
         <label class="col-form-label"> Active: </label>
         <input name="active" data-switch="true" type="checkbox" data-on-text="Yes"  data-off-text="No" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="danger">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" >
        <label class="col-form-label"> Confirmed: </label>
        <input name="confirmed" data-switch="true" type="checkbox"  data-on-text="Yes"  data-off-text="No" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="danger">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" >
        <label class="col-form-label"> Show in Search: </label>
        <input name="show" data-switch="true" type="checkbox" data-on-text="Yes"  data-off-text="No" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="danger">
    </div>
</div>
    ...

</template>

Below script changes checboxes to as shown above in image.
<script src="/assets/demo/default/custom/components/forms/widgets/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>

<script>
...
export default{}
</script>
```

Comment: You'll probably want to incorporate this code into your Vue component, instead of just attaching a separate script block somewhere.

Comment: Why are you using script tags for adding style?

Comment: What is proper way to add extra script then ? I don't know how to do it in vue

Comment: That depends on what the script does, and where in the component lifecycle you want it to run.  Vue has [excellent documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/). Give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only 1 component to be able to use it then include this js locally in that component by using `require()`:

```js
<script>
  const BootstrapSwitch = require('./assets/demo/default/custom/components/forms/widgets/bootstrap-switch.js')

  export default{
    ...
  }
```

Or use import:

```js
<script>
  import BootstrapSwitch from './assets/demo/default/custom/components/forms/widgets/bootstrap-switch.js'

  export default {
    ...
  }
```

You can also import a js module globally (e.g. in `main.js`)

Or just include it in your `.html` file as a separate `<script>` tag.

---

#### Make sure the path to the file is correct.

If the `.vue` component (that you including this js into) is not in the same folder with `assets`, then make sure to navigate to it properly.

For example, if it's 2 levels up:

```js
../../assets/demo/default/custom/components/forms/widgets/bootstrap-switch.js
```